# Finding a python process running on Windows with TaskManager

Tags: python, windows, taskmanager

I have several python.exe processes running on my Vista machine and I would like to kill one process thanks to the Windows task manager.
What is the best way to find which process to be killed. I've added the 'command line' column on task manager. It can help but not in all cases.
is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider replace Task Manager with the more powerful [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
here is a demo:[image]

Comment: Although I agree with saying that Process Explorer is a must-have, your specific example does not tell more that the Task Manager.

Comment: isn't the command line "C:\Python25\python.exe"  "D:\python\stack\stack.py" telling us the script name "stack.py" with full path instead of just a bare "python.exe"?

Comment: It does indeed, but Task Manager also provides a "command line" column (containing the same information as Process EXplorer's "command line" field.
However, Process Explorer's "Find Windows's process" tool could probably be put to good use.

Comment: @RaphaelSP, thanks for the info. the Task Manager which provides a "command line" column needs windows vista of windows 7?
I can't find it on windows xp.

Comment: Nice catch: the "command line" column only appears starting from Vista. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

When I right clicked python in task manager and clicked open file location (win 10) it opened the plex installation folder so for me it is Plex that uses Python.exe to slow my computer down, shame as I use plex all the time for my Roku. Just have to put up with a slow computer and get another one.